# does @preact/signals-react v2 supports class component?

Tags: reactjs, preact-signal

in the docs of signals react integration
https://github.com/preactjs/signals/blob/main/packages/react/README.md#react-integration

it only mentioned integration with functional components

and I tried render a signal value in a class component, but it isn't reactive at all.

```js
/* 
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@preact/signals-react": "^2.0.0",
    "@preact/signals-react-transform": "^0.3.0",
}
*/
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";
const count = signal(0);
// never re-render
class CountClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1
        onClick={() => {
          count.value = Math.random();
        }}
      >
        title{count.value}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}
// can re-render
const CountFunc = () => {
  return (
    <h1
      onClick={() => {
        count.value = Math.random();
      }}
    >
      title{count.value}
    </h1>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CountClass />
      <CountFunc />
    </div>
  )
}

createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
```

and I tried to use babel to transform the code above, the output of the class component part doesn't have any signal-related transform

```js
//...
const count = (0, _signalsReact.signal)(0);
// never re-render
class CountClass extends _react.default.Component {
  render() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("h1", {
      onClick: () => {
        count.value = Math.random();
      }
    }, "title", count.value);
  }
}
// can re-render
const CountFunc = () => {
  var _effect = (0, _runtime.useSignals)(1);
  try {
    return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("h1", {
      onClick: () => {
        count.value = Math.random();
      }
    }, "title", count.value);
  } finally {
    _effect.f();
  }
};
//...
```

Comment: Are you following the directions and using the Babel plugin?

Comment: @rschristian hi, I've updated my question, I tried babel plugin, but it doesn't work on class component, I use React 18

Comment: In that case you can still use `@preact/signals-react/auto` to get the old behavior, but do note that it is deprecated. Feel free to create an issue on the signals repo regarding class components, though I'm not sure it'll be addressed with the babel plugin.